# I have a requirement of searching a pattern from a file and displaying the pattern only in the screen,not the whole line .How can I do it in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have a requirement of searching a pattern like `x=<followed by any values>` from a file and displaying the pattern i.e  `x=<followed by any values>`, only in the screen, not the whole line. How can I do it in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 answers, from simple (but with caveats) to complex (but foolproof):

1) If your pattern never appears more than once per line, you could do this (assuming your shell is

```
PATTERN="x="
sed "s/.*\($PATTERN\).*/\1/g" your_file | grep "$PATTERN"
```

2) If your pattern can appear more than once per line, it's a bit harder. One easy but hacky way to do this is to use a special characters that will not appear on any line that has your pattern, eg, "@":

```
PATTERN="x="
SPECIAL="@"
grep "$PATTERN" your_file | sed "s/$PATTERN/$SPECIAL/g" \
  | sed "s/[^$SPECIAL]//g" | sed "s/$SPECIAL/$PATTERN/g"
```

(This won't separate the output pattern per line, eg. you'll see `x=x=x=` if a source line had 3 times "x=", this is easy to fix by adding a space in the last sed)

3) Something that always works no matter what:

```
PATTERN="x="
awk "NF>1{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) printf FS; print \"\"}" \
  FS="$PATTERN" your_file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Fabien for the above answer.                                            The above methods will give only "x=" entries whereas I need the output something like , x=3  if I'm assigning x=3 and it is inside a file many times.                                                                                                         Please let me know how do I get "x=3" output ,from a file where multiple times "x=3" is repeated inside the file?

Comment: Some moderators have pointed to an existing answer that will work for your use case too. Applying it to your case will require knowing how the x=<value> is "split" from the following characters in your text files. Assuming that there is always some whitespace (possibly a newline) after the <value>, this would work:
`grep -oh "\w*x=\w*" your_file`

Comment: Thanks a lot Fabien.It worked.